# Fault Tolerance & state management in Domain Services

Tags: domain-driven-design

In my domain, services are used to coordinate higher level behavior that involve multiple aggregates and/or other services.  Take for instance an order management system which needs to perform the following steps when canceling an order:

1. Change the state of the Order to "Canceled"
2. Reverse any pending credit card transaction
3. Add an audit entry containing an explanation why the order was canceled
4. Persist changes to the Order to the data store
5. Raise the OrderCanceledEvent (as a message)

Coding this is pretty straight-forward except there are a few additional concerns I have to implement:

- I cannot perform any of the actions if the Order is not in a
  "cancelable" state
- I cannot perform any of the actions if the current user does not have
  permission to cancel orders
- If I cannot reverse the credit card transaction then the entire
  operation should fail and the Order should remain in its original
  state
- Failing to add the audit entry does not abort the operation
- Failing to persist the Order should abort the operation and the Order
  should remain in its original state

The operation is only successful if steps 1, 2, and 4 succeed.  As a result, I cannot have these steps implemented as event handlers.

Putting aside any issues with the persistance mechanism in use (it is what it is), can you help me understand how best to implement my service so that it handles validation, errors and managing the state of the Order properly?

(I should note that I am not using Event Sourcing, so don't let the OrderCanceledEvent throw you.)

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this with event handlers is with the use of a [saga](http://kellabyte.com/2012/05/30/clarifying-the-saga-pattern/). The workflow would be as follows:

- Upon receiving `CancelOrder` command, a `OrderCancellationSaga` is started, placing the order into a `Cancelling` state.
- Upon confirmation of refund from payment gateway, the saga is completed and the order is placed into a cancelled state and persisted. At this point, within the same transaction, the `OrderCancelled` event is raised.
- If the interaction with the payment gateway fails or is declined, the order can be reverted into the prior state or placed into some sort of error state.

In this scenario auditing can occur at any stage. Also, permissions and whether the order can be cancelled in the first place should be verified before starting the saga or as a first step in starting the saga.

Rough sample with C# and [NServiceBus](http://nservicebus.com/) sagas:

```
class OrderOrderCancellationSaga : Saga<OrderCancellationSagaData>
  ,IAmStartedBy<CancelOrderCommand>,
  ,IHandle<PaymentGatewayInteractionFailedEvent> 
{

  public OrderService OrderService { get; set; }
  public PaymentGateway PaymentGateway { get; set; }

 // correlate saga messages by order ID  
 public override void ConfigureHowToFindSaga()
 {
      ConfigureMapping<PaymentGatewayInteractionFailedEvent>(x => x.OrderId, x =>x.OrderId);
      ConfigureMapping<RefundCompletedEvent>(x => x.OrderId, x => x.OrderId);
 }

  // start cancellation process
  public void Handle(CancelOrderCommand message) 
  {
     // check if cancellation is authorized and valid
     // ....

     // can save prior state here, if needed

     this.Data.OrderId = message.OrderId;
     this.Data.State = "Cancelling";    


     this.Bus.Send(new RefundOrderCommand(...));
  }

  public void Handle(RefundCompletedEvent message)
  { 
     this.Data.State = "Cancelled"; 
     this.OrderService.CompleteCancellation(...);                 
     MarkAsComplete();
  }

  // this handler can be hosted on a different endpoint.
  public void Handle(RefundOrderCommand message)
  { 
     try
     {
        this.PaymentGateway.Refund(...
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
        this.Bus.Reply(new PaymentGatewayInteractionFailedEventmessage(...));
     }
  }

  // this handler can be used to revert whole operation.
  public void Handle(PaymentGatewayInteractionFailedEvent message)
  {
     // or revert to prior state.
     this.Data.Status = "Cancellation Failed";

     // call any application services needed.

     // finishes saga, deleting state
     MarkAsComplete();
  }

}
```

Comment: Based on what I know about Sagas, they are typically implemented as domain services or command handlers which is what I am doing.  I'm also looking for something more tangible (with code examples) to illustrate how to do this.  For instance, how is the order reverted?  (Bear in mind, as I've noted in my update, I'm not using Event Sourcing.)

Comment: Yes, sagas are just message handlers that associate state with messages correlated by some key. Sagas are orthogonal to event sourcing. For examples, what language/platform are you using?

Comment: If the interaction with the payment gateway fails, the order can then be put into any state. This state can effectively "revert" the cancel operation.

Comment: Interesting.  Unfortunately we are not using NServiceBus, so the implementation doesn't exactly fit but I will review further.

Comment: The saga pattern should apply regardless, NServiceBus is just one implementation.

Comment: What's interesting is the use of events to communicate failure.  I know I've seen that before but we are not using (er, have not used) that approach so I had not considered it.